# Positive to negative dial?

Tags: voltage, switches

is there an electrical component that exists that would act similar to a potentiometer, but could be turned either clockwise or counterclockwise past a middle point, and would either release positive or negative voltage depending on which direction past that point?

So for example, you would turn it left to release a negative voltage, and turn it back to the right to release a positive voltage.

If this doesn't exist, is there a simple circuit I could create to emulate this ability?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here you are:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPD1LE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, it's exactly the same circuit you've already been doing with ground in a different place.

Comment: Sorry, but could you briefly explain the diagram to me?

Comment: The diagram is a potentiometer where ground is not connected to one of the ends of the potentiometer, but is instead at some arbitrary point in between the two ends.

Comment: I would like to comment that for this application the potentiometer should be one selected as a 'linear' resistance characteristic. Any tapered or log curve pot will not have its half resistance point in the center of rotation.

Comment: Assuming both voltages are equal. It is possible to use unequal voltages with a log or antilog pot and end up with 0V in the middle of the dial, although I can't come up with any use cases for such a setup.